# Scientific name of a lizard's reproductive system

Tags: herpetology

I need to find the scientific (latin) names of the reproductive organs of female and male lizards. So far the only result I've got is that male lizards have hemipenes inverso, but nothing on the female part.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i'd recommend wiki and google images for that.